# Set ID attribute via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to set id for image elements in a div.

```
<div id = 'div_content'>
   <img src ='img1.png'>
   <img src ='img2.png'>
</div>
```

And script:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('#div_content img');
for (var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
   items[i].attr("id","id"+i);
};
```

But it's wrong.
[image]

Comment: Where `l` comes from?

Comment: `.querySelectorAll()` won't bring you `jQuery` objects, so you can't use `jQuery` methods on them.

Comment: it loop from 0 to l = items.length. I can set .style.left, .style.top, but can not set attr 'id'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't bother using jQuery, just set the property directly.  The code's shorter and it's more efficient, too!:

```
items[i].id = 'id' + i;
```

---

NB: `items[i]` is just a DOM element, you would have had to write `$(items[i])` to turn it into a jQuery object with a `.attr` method.

Comment: @TranQuocHung please "accept" your preferred answer

Answer (score 5):

```js
$('#div_content img').each(function (index) {
   $(this).attr("id","id" + index);
});
alert($("#div_content").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = 'div_content'>
   <img src ='img1.png'>
   <img src ='img2.png'>
</div>
```

Do not use `querySelectorAll` since you already use jQuery.

```
$('#div_content img').each(function (index) {
   $(this).attr("id","id" + index);
});
```

`document.querySelectorAll` will return an array of `DOMElement`s that don't have `attr` method.

Comment: even if using jQuery to replace the call to `querySelectorAll` you should still just write `this.id = 'id' + index` inside the callback.

Comment: @Alnitak I know, but since the question was tagged with `jQuery` tag, I supposed to give jQuery answer.

Comment: true, but the trick with jQuery is knowing _when not to use it..._